# BeforeEach with expectGets cannot be executed more then once

Tags: unit-testing, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a problem with my unit test for a directive where I need to setup the directive before being able to test it.

This is the way I initialize it:

```
var elm, $templateCache
var count = 0;

beforeEach(module('app/js/directives/templates/mytemplate.html'));


beforeEach(inject(function($injector) {
    $templateCache = $injector.get('$templateCache');
}));

beforeEach(inject(
        ['$httpBackend','$compile','$rootScope', function(_$compile) {
            var template = $templateCache.get('app/js/directives/templates/mytemplate.html');
            if(count == 0 ){
                $httpBackend.expectGET('js/directives/templates/mytemplate.html').respond(template);
            }

            elm = angular.element('<div my-directive</div>');
            $compile(elm)($rootScope);


            if(count == 0){


                $httpBackend.expectGET('/app/js/content/some.json').respond('{ "left" : "<div>Contact information</div>"}');

                $httpBackend.flush();
            }

            $rootScope.$digest();
            count++;
        }]
    ));

afterEach(function() {
    $httpBackend.verifyNoOutstandingExpectation();
    $httpBackend.verifyNoOutstandingRequest();
});


it("should work like I want it to", function() {
    $rootScope.my-directive.somefunction();
    expect($rootScope.somevalue).toBe(2);
});

it("should load the previous page if the function scope.layover.qa_pager.prev is called", function() {
    $rootScope.my-directive.someotherfunction();
    expect($rootScope.somevalue).toBe(1);
});
```

This works, but the hack with the count should not be needed in my opinion. If I leave it out I get problems with the $httpbackend which doesn't seem to be reinitialised every time so it gives me 'Error: Unsatisfied requests: GET /app/js/content/some.json' and 'Error: No pending request to flush !'

Answer (score 0):

To me it looks like you are trying to load a template for a unit test. I'm assuming you are using karma to run the tests, so you should look at html2js. It loads your templates into the template cache for you.

https://github.com/karma-runner/karma-ng-html2js-preprocessor

```
// karma.conf.js
module.exports = function(config) {
  config.set({
    preprocessors: {
      '**/*.html': ['ng-html2js']
    },

    files: [
      '*.js',
      '*.html'
    ],

    ngHtml2JsPreprocessor: {
      // strip this from the file path
      stripPrefix: 'public/',
      // prepend this to the
      prependPrefix: 'served/',

      // or define a custom transform function
      cacheIdFromPath: function(filepath) {
        return cacheId;
      }
    }
  });
};
```

Comment: I did try that, but the ng-html2js is for a newer karma which our team cannot use yet, and I do need the path mangling..